# Passive Ethernet Hub / Point to Multipoint Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, hub

I have a device which needs to connect to one of three devices using ethernet. When one device  is connected, the other 2 will be powered down. Power consumption is a factor, so I'd like to use a passive component

Using a RJ45 splitter has failed, I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion for this architecture

Would a single ethernet cable with 4 end terminations work?
Is there anything off the shelf for this situation?

Best regards

Comment: I assume [10Base2 Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2) with it's passive BNC T-pieces is out of the question :-)

Comment: max data we are going to be pushing is ~2MBps the  only problem is the devices terminate with RJ45

Answer (score 2):

The two problems is that while the devices might be turned off, there is still standby power. The ethernet cards can still be active at the base level. Which is why Wake On Lan works.

You could try a 4 pole, 3 position switch. This is the same type of switch used in radios, or more computer oriented, vga switches. Quality isn't always the best.
[image]

[image]

The better question is why is power consumption an issue? Can't you tap into the power from one of the devices?